# TexMaker creates many (1) (2) (3) aux files with associated pdf files, and the reference is very unreliable

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, cross-referencing

I am facing a quite frustrating problem with my Latex compiler on my MacBook Pro .
The referencing (both the citation references and fig/table reference) is very unreliable. If I clean everything it works after three compilation (pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex). There are though a few undefined fig/table reference even though they are correct. If I repeat the process the undefined reference becomes something else.

Now the problem is after the third compilation, if I do a fourth I would expect everything to work, at least with the citations. But no, not even a single citation reference works and it appears as though I need to clean up everything again.
When inspecting my folder I realise I have a bunch of files like this :

```
 thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (2).aux
  thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (2).lof
  thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (2).lot
  thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (2).toc
  thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (3).aux
  thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (3).lof
  thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (3).lot
  thesis-XXX`s MacBook Pro (3).toc
```

etc...
It continues down to (6) or more if I keep compiling. The `XXX` is my Macbook's name

I have tried to test this with a windows Machine also using TexStudio. The Windows machine is based on MikTex. For the windows machine it is works perfectly

Comment: you seem to regularly change the name of the main file. Perhaps some backup system kicking in? Or your editor can't save the file and so creates a new version?

Comment: What are you using as a front-end?

Comment: I am using TexStudio

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not changing the main file's name. Although, I do have other folder in the computer with Latex projects that have same main file name. But again, these are on separate folders

Comment: I should probably also add that my Latex project folder is stored on oneDrive rather than physically on the computer. Don't know if that makes a difference

Comment: Can you try using a local folder, just to test whether OneDrive is the issue?

Comment: It looks like that was the issue indeed @WillieWong